# Automate Script, Path folder name changes

Tags: python, path

I am in the process of making an automated script. Basically I am downloading some shapefiles, unzipping them and them making a few changes each month. Each month I download the same dataset.

An issue I have found is that the dataset name changes each month after I download it, I'm not sure how i can point the script too it if the name changes? I don't really want to have to update the script with the new file path each month.

For example November was

```
L:\load\Ten\Nov20\NSW\FME_68185551_1604301077137_7108\GSNSWDataset
```

And Dec is

```
L:\load\Ten\Dec20\NSW\FME_68185551_1606880934716_1252\GSNSWDataset
```

---

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yep i just added

Comment: The issue is "FME_68185551_1606880934716_1252". These numbers change each month. How do i still point the script to it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use glob with a wildcard in the changing number section. Something like:

```
import glob
import datetime

d = datetime.today().strftime('%b%y') #'Dec20'

fil = glob.glob("L:/load/Ten/%s/NSW/FME*/GSNSWDataset" % (d))[0]
```

This should get you the correct path to your files and then you just read/manipulate however you need.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, also backslashes will make the path wrong, you need to add `r` before the string or use double backslashes or use normal slashes

Comment: Ah, yes, I just copied and pasted the path so that's fixed. How does it not answer the question?

Comment: She needs to get the newest file

Comment: I mean updating the month part to get the next file is easy because it's the same format each time. What she was asking about was how to handle the somewhat random number section, which a wildcard does.

Comment: Now it's better, it would be good if checking for existing of the file was added

Comment: @Jtradfor Yay thank you it worked!. Just so i understand though how come the %s is used for date instead of {}?   I used this and it worked `fil = glob.glob("L:/Support/Data_load/Tenements/%s/NSW/FME*/GSNSWDataset/TitlesCurrent.shp" % (d))[0]`

Comment: Glad it worked! %s is just an old way to do string formatting. An alternative to how you used '{}'.format()